# Is it possible to make a reversible "Solid State" Hydrogen fuel cell using Ammonia Borane and Iron Oxide?

Tags: electrochemistry, hydrogen, fuel, oxygen

Well, I saw [this video](https://youtu.be/fJuIkZv8ks8) about hydrogen reduction, in which pure hydrogen gas is exposed to iron oxide at high temperatures, producing water vapor and leaving pure iron behind.

And as such, I wondered if there was a way of instead of an hydrogen reduction, there was a "oxygen reduction" so to speak, in which a material "carrier" with a lot of hydrogen bonds reacts with oxygen, generating water and leaving a pure material carrier behind.

Unfortunately, I'm not quite knowledgeable in chemistry, so I asked a *lot* of questions to ChatGPT on the subject, and although it has a lot of limitations, I received answers that *seemed* to make sense.

---

But I'm asking here to know if what it suggested is actually true:

It suggested using either LiNH2-BH3 (Lithium Amidoborane-Borane), NaNH2-LiH (Sodium Amide-Lithium Hydride) or Ammonia Borane (NH3BH3).

And accordingly to ChatGPT, the Ammonia borane would have up to 20% of weight reacted with hydrogen, and once it reacted with the oxygen in the iron oxide, it would leave behind ammonia and boron nitride. The ammonia/nitrogen would be "stored" on a copper oxide metal ammine complex (again, accordingly to ChatGPT).

Then, in order to "charge" the cells by using a reversible hydrogen fuel cell, one would generate pure hydrogen and pure oxygen from water and react everything back to its original state. Just like a battery.

6kg of hydrogen + 16kg of ammonia + 13kg of boron nitride + 16kg of copper metal ammine complex  + 3kg of oxygen + 6kg of iron powder = 60kg in total.
And 6kg of hydrogen is more or less 720 megajoules or 200,000 watt-hours, but with inneficiencies, it would be quite lower value.

Of course, this is ChatGPT we are talking about, it is an AI model that makes statements and answers that sound true.

In one of question in particular, it suggested that Tuolene had a capacity of adsorption of 96% of hydrogen per kg of weight. Which is not true and once I pointed it out, the AI admited it was incorrect.

In any case, I seems interesting to make a solid hydrogen fuel cell, but if it was actually possible, I sure would have seen a lot of news on the subject already.

Comment: Safe storage and consumption of hydrogen is one of the key research areas of synthetic fuels. Since we're still burning the fossil stuff, it's a long way coming. I'm afraid your question doesn't fit our format. FWIW: LLM juggle with language, they don't make sense of what they write. As such you could have "corrected" a fact that would have been correct in the first place. Please don't waste valuable fossil fuels on asking a dumb machine things it cannot possibly comprehend.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン This is a question's website, I've made a question. How I'm going to know if what the ChatGPT said is incorrect if no one answers? :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your original question is no. An iron oxide-ammonia borane fuel cell will not work because the reaction is endothermic. I'll go into a bit more detail though.

### ChatGPT gave you its usual frothy mixture of truth, lies, and complete nonsense.

I'll help you tease it out, but in reality you should just reject the whole thing.

> It suggested using either LiNH2-BH3 (Lithium Amidoborane-Borane), NaNH2-LiH (Sodium Amide-Lithium Hydride) or Ammonia Borane (NH3BH3).

These are all real compounds that have been considered for use in fuel cells. However, to the extent that ChatGPT suggests they *will* work, don't believe it. Let's say they're among the candidates for a hydrogen storage material.

> accordingly to ChatGPT, the Ammonia borane would have up to 20% of weight reacted with hydrogen

Ammonia borane is 20% (actually 19.6%) hydrogen by weight. However, you can't access all that hydrogen efficiently and reversibly -- an important detail that GPT left out.

> once it reacted with the oxygen in the iron oxide, it would leave behind ammonia and boron nitride

OK, here's where it goes totally off the rails.

One big problem with this whole idea is that hydrogen reduction of iron oxide to iron is *endothermic*. You have to put in energy to do that, rather than getting energy out. This is worth it when you're making steel, but obviously the opposite of what you want in a fuel cell. The same problem occurs with ammonia borane. According to my calculation for the reaction $\ce{NH3.BH3 + Fe2O3 -> BN + 2Fe + 3H2O}$, the change in enthalpy is +90 kJ/mol. That's the wrong direction. There are other problems too, though.

At the high temperatures where iron oxide is reduced by hydrogen, it would likely react with ammonia too, so that would not be the final product. In fact, ammonia reduction [has been proposed](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/advs.202300111) as an alternative to hydrogen reduction for steel production. (This proposal makes no practical sense to me, but it shows that at temperatures where hydrogen reacts with iron oxide, ammonia probably isn't stable either.)

The stoichiometry of GPT's proposed reaction doesn't work.

Overall I rate this part as ranging between wrong and nonsense.

> The ammonia/nitrogen would be "stored" on a copper oxide metal ammine complex (again, accordingly to ChatGPT).

Copper ammine complexes are a thing that exists, but there's no reason to believe they would be a good storage mechanism under fuel cell conditions. They also can't store nitrogen gas. This is just totally made up and useless.

> Then, in order to "charge" the cells by using a reversible hydrogen fuel cell, one would generate pure hydrogen and pure oxygen from water and react everything back to its original state. Just like a battery.

This again is just totally made up. It's the fuel cell chemistry version of the "draw the rest of the damn owl" meme... "then just react everything back to the original state!" While it is relatively easy to re-oxidize your iron, getting the other side back to the original ammonia borane will be a real challenge.

The efficiency of water splitting is also pretty bad.

### Conclusion

ChatGPT gave you very little of value here, and a lot of lies and incomplete information.

I'll give it credit for one thing -- it listed some hydrogen storage materials. Everything else it told you is wrong or devastatingly incomplete and misleading. And, most importantly, it completely failed to tell you the real problem with your idea.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) (some mods say that I need to wait at least 24hours before checking an asnwer btw)